# When use email provider password, can I use jwt token, save it in the database and have it checked?

Tags: next.js, jwt, next.js13, next-auth

nextjs 13 in app router /w next-auth

How can I include jwt token when logging in with a passwordless email provider?

[...nextauth]

```
  const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {...
    providers: [
          EmailProvider({
       sendVerificationRequest: sendVerificationRequestApi,
       session: {
          strategy: 'jwt',
       },
       callbacks: {
          async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user.id) token._id = user.id;
            return token;
          },
        },
    }
    const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
    
    export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

senverificationApi.tsx

```
  const { identifier, url, provider, theme } = params
   const tag = 'sendVerificationRequestApi'
    const email1 = provider.from

   const token = jwt.sign({ email1 }, process.env.JWT_SECRET!, { expiresIn: '15m' }) as string;
       const smtp_transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
             host: SMTP_HOST,
             port: SMTP_PORT || 587,
             secure: false, // for STARTTLS keep secure needs to be false. use true only for TLS/SSL
             connectionTimeout: 10000,
             socketTimeout: 10000,
             greetingTimeout: 10000,
             dnsTimeout: 10000,
             auth: {
                user: SMTP_USER,
                pass: SMTP_PASSWORD,
             }, // <-- added comma here
          } as SMTPTransport.Options)
```

Here I can receive data via SMTP, it comes in the e-mail, verification comes from LinkedIn.
i want to use jwt token when saving mongodb how ?

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        const res = await signIn("email", {
          callbackUrl: "/",
          email: Email,
          redirect: false, // We will forward to /auth/verify-request manually with query params (We need email address at verify-request page)
        });
        if (res?.status == 200) {
          console.log("başarılı");
        } else {
          console.log("Auth Error", Email);
          // router.push({ pathname: `/auth/error` });
        }
  };
  return (
  );
```